# MbUnit 3.0 Separate Download

Tags: mbunit

I want to get MBUnit 3.0, but without the Gallio bundling.. not sure whether such a package is available or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the bundle and then just pull out the MbUnit assemblies if you have another way that you want to run them instead of using Gallio.

Answer (score 1):

Get the zip (GallioBundle-3.0.6.763.zip) file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/downloads/list) and get only the MBUnit assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Gallio has a plugin architecture.  So while MbUnit is based on Gallio, you don't need to install all of the extra plugins on the side unless you need them.  The minimum set of required components is fairly small.

As Rodrigo said, there is a ZIP file distribution available which does not require installation in order to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the MbUnit is based upon Gallio so it's not possible to get them separately.